# How to integrate client certificate with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, keytool

I am facing issue with the execution of the APIs in Jmeter. Our APIs have client certificate in .pfx format. I have converted the same in .jks and updated the same in the system.properties of jmeter. In jmeter I have created a csv file to pick up the created alias. However, the error is shown as

**Error:**
Response message: Non HTTP response message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No certificate found for alias:'certalias'

**Below is my alias info:**
Alias name: certalias
Creation date: Nov 8, 2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:

**Jmeter Log:**
2018-11-13 11:16:08,949 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore

Can you please help me with the integration of our client certificate with the Jmeter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your test plan and content of system.properties ? thx

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to convert the .pfx into as .pfx is a [PKCS12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) certificate type and JMeter should support it out of the box.

Make sure to add the next lines to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=your_certificate.pfx
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up.

If you have > 1 certificates in the keystore you can select the exact certificate(s) by setting the [following properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#ssl_config)

```
https.keyStoreStartIndex=0
https.keyStoreEndIndex=0
```

By default JMeter will go for the first certificate in the keystore, if your `certalias` is not the first - amend the properties accordingly.

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: Thank you, This helped. But Dev team do not want to share the .pfx password as in Jmeter the password is not hidden.. So I was looking out for an alternate with .jks where we can have our own password

Comment: What do they mean by `password is not hidden`? If there is a problem with storing the password in *system.properties* file it can be [overridden via -D command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like `jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password`. Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about different types of JMeter properties and ways of setting and overiding them.